# Invalid JWT signature after converting to exe

Tags: python, selenium, gspread

I am working on a selenium project, when I wanted to test it on pycharm, it worked just well, but when I extracted it to exe, it gave me this error `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})` Does any one know why?

PS: my clock is not the problem cause I made some research

Tried Solution: Change the Clock of the system

Code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def sheet_access(sheet_name, worksheet_name):
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open(sheet_name).worksheet(worksheet_name)
    return sheet
```

Full Error:

```
  File "google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 476, in request
  File "google\auth\credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
  File "google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 407, in refresh
  File "google\oauth2\_client.py", line 193, in jwt_grant
  File "google\oauth2\_client.py", line 165, in _token_endpoint_request
  File "google\oauth2\_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
```

Comment: I had a same issue , I just create a new private key from google cloud platform

  IAM & admin -> Service accounts 
Service accounts for project "Project_Name"

already created your Service account,click on the actions-> Create Key

and update the private key on your project. Hope it will help you.

Comment: this answer is the key